# Left sided exponent in expressions

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

Normal exponents in expressions are done via `expression("C"^13 * "some string")`.
However, I now need a possibility to make such an exponent on the **left** side, like it is needed for the correct description of Carbon-13 (example: [image: Left sided exponent])

I need to write 13C for a figure-title in ggplot2.

Is there an expression-notation to do that? Or another way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a blank + superscript 13, juxtaposed with C.

```r
ggplot() + 
   ggtitle(expression("Something having to do with "^13*"C"~" concentrations"))
```

If you need 13-C at the beginning of the string, you can use an empty string (`expression(""^13*"C")`)

This is the way that most people do it in LaTeX as well (i.e. `${}^13\textrm{C}$`), although the [isotope package for LaTeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/isotope) states that this is typographically unsatisfactory ...